# A word or phrase for 'Holy grail' (a goal impossible to achieve)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that means "a long sought out goal that seems impossible to achieve" but without any religious connotations. Any suggestions?

My intended usage is as follows:

> The *holy grail* in ABC is to identify XYZ

where ABC is an academic field of study and XYZ is a solution approach with desired features.

Comment: Hi Aditya. Welcome to EL&U. Can you please include information on how the word or phrase will be used with a possible example?

Comment: @ermanen: I added information on how I plan to use the word/phrase.

Comment: The word you're looking for is [_MacGuffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)._

Comment: Using your term, Don Quixote (via Luther Vandross) strives *to dream the impossible dream*.

Comment: No, not *MacGuffin*

Comment: @JohnLawler I laughed so hard, my dog is now looking at me funny.  You're spot on.  MacGuffin is the word!

Comment: In some contexts you could call such a goal the person's Great White Whale. Of course, that would imply an unhealthy obsession.

Comment: Hm.  Have you considered "holy grail?"

Comment: How about "unobtanium".

Comment: Do you believe this goal is attainable, or do you consider it impossible? Something clearly attainable but not yet reached might be the "Pinnacle" or the "Ultimate".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Phrases like "the Holy Grail of Physics", are [snowclones of the form "Z is the X of Y"](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/003394.html). They work because X's properties are well-understood and can be used to immediately relate Z and Y.

So if someone says

> Artificial Intelligence is the Holy Grail of Computer Science

Then everyone knows what that means: AI is something that is rumoured to exist (or be possible to create) and it is as fervently desired to computer scientists as the real Holy Grail would be to religious people/Indiana Jones.

The point of all of this is that it doesn't matter what X is; all that matters is that when "the X of Y" is put together, you understand what the comparison is.

Examples:

> The [Switzerland of Africa](http://www.africa-ata.org/guinea_excursion_1.htm)
>
> The [Elvis of hip hop](http://www.daveyd.com/commentaryiseminemelvis.html)

etc.

**The reason I say all of this in answer to your question is that "The Holy Grail of Y" doesn't have religious connotation, and it's the best phrase to use.** It's a mythical object that has been the source of quests to discover its location, etc. It has inspired many fictional tales. People dream of finding it. There is scant reason to believe it could actually exist, but it is plausible. Its origin is in literature, not religious practice. So use "the Holy Grail of Y", just like you freely say "Good-bye" without [worrying about its etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-goodbye).

A further reason to use this phrase is because it only works when people get your reference. Example: bib's comment below, where his father calls himself "the Derek Jeter of mussels", was completely opaque to me because I have no idea who Derek Jeter is. If you find a synonym, such as [Andrew Leach's "El Dorado"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187131/380), which actually suits your meaning, you have to be careful that it is obvious why you are making the connection. Everyone knows what the *Holy Grail of Y* is. People might not understand what the *El Dorado of Y* is.

Comment: My 90 year-old father, upon completing a large bowl of shellfish, declared himself to be *the Derek Jeter of mussels!*.

Comment: Agreed: the Holy Grail is the MacGuffin of the King Arthur legends. Its origin is literary, not religious.

Comment: OP might have meant something that does not sound religious. To me, "Holy Grail" sounds like religious and the origin has religious connotations as you mentioned. Even the word "holy" itself evokes religious connotations. Though this answer is a nice explanation about the phrase and the phrase you mentioned is used in non-religious contexts.

Comment: It has about as much religious connotation as "Holy cow!" does.

Comment: Not really. "Holy Cow!" is an exclamation and has this funny element in it. Though, the analysis of the word "holy" might be discussed in another question.

Comment: This is a snowclone in the same sense as it is an expression. This is not specific enough, and most of this answer doesn't have anything to do with the question (I'm not sure if the question has been edited). From the link you gave us, a number of other plug-and-play cliches (that have nothing to do with unattainable goals) are also snowclones.

Comment: @Asad a "snowclone" is ['a type of cliché and phrasal template'.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) For example, "Pink is the new Black" is a phrase that got a lot of currency at one point. "X is the new Y" then becomes a snowclone when people start saying things like "Serverfault is the StackOverflow" or whatever. The base form of _the OP's snowclone_ is "Z is the X of Y". It is a pattern that must be followed. I explained why the pattern almost demands "holy grail" in this case.

Comment: @Asad So yes, things that have nothing to do with unattainable goals are snowclones. That's not relevant though. What matters is that the snowclone works because the template establishes an order, a relationship, and that relationship is meaningful because of the cultural context.

Comment: @ermanen: just because the word "holy" is in there it does not imply a religious meaning to the sentence. "Holy grail" is such a commonly used expression that any religious connotation is lost. It may, however make you think of killer rabbits and african swallows...

Comment: @nico: You misunderstood what I said. But I think it is not important anymore. I did not know that explanation of "Holy Grail" was the aim of this question. I thought we were finding something other than that.

Comment: @ermanen: *Holy cow!* is presumably funny only to people who do not view cows as sacred. ;-) (Yes, it seems that the etymology is not clear. There are the euphemists (!) who think it covers *Holy Christ!*, those who think that it is from western travelers to India, and those who claim that it refers to the biblical Golden Calf.)

Comment: Another advantage of 'Holy Grail' over some metaphors you might consider, is that it remains theoretically achievable (no known counter-proof) but after N centuries, you can be highly confident that the phrase won't become amusingly obsolete while your paper is still relevant. Unlike, say, "Cure for cancer", "self-driving car" or "SETI" for example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to mention an interesting phrase: ***[ultima thule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule)***

> The term **ultima Thule** in medieval geographies denotes any distant place located beyond the "borders of the known world".
>
> Virgil coined the term Ultima Thule (Georgics, 1. 30) meaning furthest land as a symbolic reference to denote a far-off land or **an unattainable goal.**
>
> <sub>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule</sub>

It is still used today in this symbolic sense.

---

There is also ***[will-o'-the-wisp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will-o%27-the-wisp)***

> a goal that cannot be reached, a delusive or elusive goal

It originally means the atmospheric ghost lights seen at night over marshy grounds. But it is used in this symbolic sense in literature.

> <sub>Source:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will-o%27-the-wisp</sub>

---

Other than that, there is ***[a pipe dream](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+pipe+dream)*** but it wouldn't be suitable for your context. It is worth to mention because it is related.

> an idea that could never happen because it is impossible
>
> *The classless society is just a pipe dream.*
>
> <sub>Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+pipe+dream</sub>

---

**Note:** I gave this answer in another question which is closed.

Comment: _(Ultima) Thule_ was the first thing I thought of too. +1 for that. Not sure _pipe dream_ is really a good choice given the usage example, though—the Holy Grail of something may be unrealistic, but it's _worth going for_; a pipe dream is something best dropped ’cause you'll never get there anyway.

Comment: *Ultima Thule* is a wonderful term. Great suggestion. On the other hand, I think that *pipe dream* is not quite appropriate in this context.

Comment: Ultima thule is a great choice if you don't want anyone to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Wonderful phrase, thank you! @emodendroket – That can only change through the efforts of people like us :-)

Answer (score 4):

In some cases ***El Dorado*** could be a possibility for something which is much sought-after but ultimately unachievable. As it's a Spanish expression from the South American Conquest, the phrase has never had any religious connotations.

> During the 16th and 17th centuries, Europeans, still fascinated by and ignorant of the New World, believed that a hidden city of immense wealth existed. Many searched for this treasure, in quests that ended in the loss of countless lives. The illustration of El Dorado's location on maps only made matters worse, as it made some people think that the city of El Dorado's existence had been confirmed. The mythical city of El Dorado on Lake Parime was marked on English and other maps until its existence was disproved by Alexander von Humboldt during his Latin-America expedition (1799–1804)
>
> [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Dorado#From_ritual_to_myth_and_metaphor)]

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a synonym, that actually fits. However, in my opinion it's not as clear as "the Holy Grail of X", mainly because I don't think anybody uses it this way. +1 though for a good synonym.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid colloquialisms in an academic paper, in part because they require knowledge — and a shared understanding — of a domain irrelevant to the actual discourse.

Avoid colloquialisms even in informal writing for the same reason: you’re trying to guide the reader’s thoughts and emotions, and colloquialisms can divert the reader into thoughts like those expressed above.

If I needed it, I’d stick with *Holy Grail*. None of the alternatives offered conveys the same meaning.

However, using it doesn't transform the discussion into a religious matter, and most educated people will at least know the reference — just as they should also know something about the rest of the world’s great religions. If not, you can have a nice chat with the person you’re speaking with and bring the world a little closer together.

Comment: +1 for all 3 points you raised, but especially the last two: (2) it's the best, (3) it's not about religion.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is *Moonshot*. A *moonshot* is usually a highly risky attempt to reach a very rewarding goal. It's when success seems unlikely, but you're going for it anyway.

For a discussion of the word, see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159638/what-does-moonshots-mean).

As an example use of the word, here's a WSJ headline from today:

> Google's New Moonshot Project: the Human Body

Comment: I think this is the best answer, aside from "Holy Grail" itself.

Comment: I like this answer but I think a "moonshot" is different from a "holy grail". The moonshot is risky and hard to do and expensive, but clearly possible. The holy grail may not even exist and nobody knows what it might cost to find it... it could be easily found or require a very costly search. But if found, it constitutes a major victory with potentially huge ramifications. The moonshot, by contrast, is more of an engineering challenge than a revolutionary discovery waiting to be discovered.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Yes, that's a fair point. The two are conceptually slightly different. However, in many contexts, they're used to refer to similar things.

Comment: I disagree with the contention that a "moonshot" is clearly possible.  Part of the risk is that it indeed may not be.  One of Google's moonshot projects is human immortality.  Is that definitely possible?  Who knows!

Comment: "Moonshot" implies a one-time, hopeful effort to attain something desirable, while "Holy Grail" is the actual desirable thing. A "Holy Grail" has already been subject to continual pursuit.One can try a Moonshot to attain a Holy Grail, for instance.

Comment: @pimlottc: Google's self-proclaimed immortality moonshot might be unattainable, and it is in any case **not understood** today. But the mechanics of the moonshot itself were understood 100s of years ago, and the technology needed was clear when the project was adopted. What was not clear was that it could be realized within the projected decade (1960s). A moonshot is a difficult and grandiose project. But it is more likely to be based on a good deal of knowledge and detailed planning than is the reaching of a *holy grail*. When AI gets a lot closer it might make it from holy grail to moonshot.

Comment: @user77595: Good point. But *moonshot* can mean both the project to attain a moon landing and the landing itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could say you're...

> [*searching for the pot of gold*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22much%20of%20the%20same%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22searching%20for%20the%20pot%20of%20gold%22&tbm=bks) [at the end of the rainbow] (thousands of hits in Google Books)

...but the strong implication there is that goal *really is unreachable* (it doesn't just *seem* so). Note that the idiomatic usage is so well known that just ***pot of gold*** is all that's needed...

> *I take it that the "pot of gold" for most of us is happiness* [(The Rotarian - Oct 1938)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FUEEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22the%20pot%20of%20gold%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FXvSU5a5K_Cw7AaU9oHoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20pot%20of%20gold%20for%22&f=false)

Comment: Also, the *Golden Fleece*. But that apparently wasn't impossible since Jason got it.

Comment: @bib: I couldn't say ***Golden Fleece*** has *never* been used "figuratively" in that way, but I've never come across it that I recall. And whereas my cited *Rotarian* example above seems a perfectly natural usage to me, I'd find it really "odd" if ***pot of gold*** were replaced by ***Golden Fleece***.

Comment: I don't really disagree, hence the upvote.

Comment: I'm sure I would recognise the figurativeness of "golden fleece" if it was in quotes.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I can't begin to imagine what a "literal" *golden fleece* might mean, so I guess all references to it must to to some extent "figurative". But it's rarely referenced outside the context of Jason and the Argonauts.

Comment: I would be swayed in favour of the golden fleece given that it seems more unattainable. As for their contexts, both come from something mythological, the only real difference when viewed abstractly is that one is Irish and one is Greek.

Comment: @Pharap: First, as bib says, the golden fleece clearly *was* "obtainable" (Jason's quest was successful). Secondly, even if the pot of gold *did* exist, it would still be unobtainable (the laws of physics prevent you from approaching the "end" of the rainbow).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In which case, surely it's the 'end' of the rainbow that is the unattainable thing, both figuratively and literally.

Answer (score 1):

Right. If you are writing an academical paper, I would entirely avoid the "holy grail" concept. In science there are no such things as "holy grails". (It would make you sound naive or not used to scientific papers.)

Personally, just my opinion, a simple expression such as:

"one of the most important and still unsolved problems in ABC is ..."

or something like that, might work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

'Sisyphean task'--an impossible task. Named after Sisyphus, the king of ancient Corinth who blasphemed the gods and was condemned to Hades where his penalty was to forever roll a boulder up a hill to the top. But he was so fatigued by the effort as he pushed the boulder higher, he had to halt and the boulder rolled back to the bottom of the hill--and the effort had to be repeated for all eternity.

Answer (score 1):

As this is about academic fields, I would take a well known metaphor from the time-honoured field of alchemy:

"The philosopher's stone in ABC is to identify XYZ."

If you are *really* sure it's not achievable, you can also put it this way:

"The squaring of the circle in ABC would be to identify XYZ."

Comment: Gah, beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not really trying to suggest impossiblity, just the extreme difficulty and rarity of the achievement, you might try *[Everest](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/everest)*

> high point; summit: *The book is an Everest in the field of historical scholarship*. [*Infoplease Dictionary*]

Similarly in [*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/everest)*]

> any high point of ambition or achievement

Answer (score -1):

You could say *chasing after the sun*.

Answer (score -1):

If your audience is mathematical (or scientific/technical) several examples spring to mind.

This suggests it may be solvable in a half millennium or so:

> The Fermat Theorem in ABC is to identify XYZ.

This suggests the problem solution is just getting under way:

> The Riemann Hypothesis in ABC is to identify XYZ.

And these suggest that the problem is going to take a while:

> XYZ in ABC could have been one of Hilbert's Problems.

or

> XYZ in ABC is a Millennium Prize Problem candidate.

Mathematics is rather rich in "long sought out goal[s] that seem...impossible to achieve"

Answer (score -2):

How about saying *the Higgs particle of X*?

Comment: But they found the Higgs particle (statistically speaking)

Answer (score -2):

idk. I say "notable" because it is a fact that has particular significance or insight into how or to what end. lol

"In a notable study of the information systems technolgoy program, the project life cycle has projected new insights into developing a superior technology."

Comment: OP asked for a word or phrase with the sense "a long sought out goal that seems impossible to achieve". "notable" does not have this sense. A Holy Grail would probably (but not necessarily) be notable, but one cannot infer that a notable thing is a Holy Grail.